# Trying to authenticate through a POST method python webscraping

Tags: python, http, request

Trying to automate in python the login to this website: https://app.rotoql.com/tools/dk/nba/optimizer

You need to be authenticated to access the page. I decided to check the developer console to see if I can somehow auth into the page with python so I can webscrape it.

Here is what it looked like in the console:
[image]

So I wrote my corresponding python code as:

```
LoginURL = 'https://api.rotoql.com/app/user/login'
RequestURL = 'https://app.rotoql.com/tools/dk/nba/players'
session = requests.Session()
data = {"email":"jac1008@wildcats.unh.edu","password":""}
session.post(LoginURL, data=data)
r = session.get(RequestURL)
print(r.content)
```

(pulled out the password)

but the only page I got back was the 'Login required' page. Does anyone out there have any idea on how I would actually pull this off? I've been googling a good bit, and it seems like I am sending the data payload correctly, I am also using a post request but it dosen't seem to work.

Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

we can directly use auth on RequestURL. plz try below code

```
session.post(RequestURL, auth=('username', 'password'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have to provide headers with `user-agent` and all to tell the server that the request is coming from a browser

Create a head dictionary from `Request Header` values

```
head={'User-Agent':'Mozilla....', ....}
```

Then

```
session.post(LoginURL, data=data,headers=head)
```

This worked for me.